# Want to Use Different Targets on different unity buttons

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Hi I need help to create buttons on unity screen and set different targets on each button. I set buttons with unity UI > Buttons, But I unable to set target on each button, like it start targeting usd on usd click, not others. Please help me. I will be very Thankful to you.

Comment: By looking at the comments under the answer below, you really do need to learn Unity from scratch. It's not Java and it's not Android Studio. If you understand the basic Unity stuff, you can then jump into AR stuff. There are many tutorials on [their](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) site with different categories.

Comment: I will , But now its urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created UI button, in your inspector select your button, then

-look for the button script in the inspector,then

-look for "On click"

-Then select your gameobject with "scriptButtonQuit"

-then in the next selection box , select "scriptButtonQuit" -> "onClick()"

[image: Unity Button UI]

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, but i don't know how what should I write on script, im a native android developer. But I don't know how to create it. :|

Comment: Add each button with onCick() method and assign different method name.

Comment: Please help me, Check this link

Comment: In the image, you select your AR Camera, so it shows AR Camera in inspector ? @PawandeepKaur

Comment: yes, It is. But I don't know how to put code on click

Comment: If i understood your problem correctly, which is; **when you click a button some function will work.** If this is your case, I strongly suggest you to watch some tutorials about it if you havent any. One from [Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button). One from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQ2Qc_0MIyI) @PawandeepKaur

Comment: Thanks @EmreE , on Urgent basis I want how to use step by step, In My office there is privacy on youtube, I cant check YT link.

Comment: @PawandeepKaur Harsh on privacy. Although Umesh Verma 's answer is pretty solid. I'll try to write it down a simple one. Create a function which debug log "Clicked". Add this script to an object. Create a UI button. It has component **Button**. There is `on Click()` function on it. Drag your object which has the script on to `on Click()`. After on the right from dropDown choose your function which debug logs ("Clicked"). When you clicked the UI Button, it should run your function, so ("Clicked") will be printed on the console.

Comment: Hi @Umesh Im working on android vuforia sample now, I have change the target there but teapoat isn't visible by detecting image targets. Can you Please help.

Comment: @EmreE  Please check my above comment.

Comment: Hi @Pawandeep Kaur, Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Thanks for reply @UmeshVerma Please check https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/vuforia-sample-teapot-not-showing

Comment: HI @PawandeepKaur, I am not pretty much sure for this but I can suggest you to debug your Scene, Move your camera and check your teapot object and its position. May be its position is not lie inside your target camera position...

Comment: @UmeshVerma Did you worked on AR android studio sample?